# Why is "brazen" translated as "bronze"?

Tags: traducción, inglés

In the English edition of "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn" (at least the version available on gutenberg.org), this sentence appears:

*"It's the brazen serpent in the wilderness!*

The Spanish translation found elsewhere is:

*«¡Es la serpiente de bronce del desierto!*

If I'm not mistaken, a reverse translation would be, "*It is the bronze serpent of the desert!*"

Why is "brazen" translated as "bronze"?

**Note:** in actuality, the serpent on the pole (which was made when the Israelites were wandering in the desert) was said to be of copper, not bronze (see [this](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-stories/3/copper-snake/) for the details).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Brazen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brazen) has multiple meanings in English. The most common is "bold", but a more archaic (and chiefly literary) secondary definition is "made of brass".

Comment: Very interesting; and both brass and bronze are alloys which contain copper

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @ukemi and according to the Cambridge Dictionary

[brazen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brazen)

> Made of brass

**brass** translates into Spanish as **latón**, a different alloy from **bronze** although they both contain copper.

I think that probably the translator considered it a typo, that "branze" was really "bronze" and translated it accordingly to "bronce".